# How can I fix ValidationError of Sass loader?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2

I was trying to add global scss variables to my Vue project. I found this example [Globally load sass](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/). So I created `vue.config.js` in my root folder of my Vue project then I copy & paste `vue.config.js` and change the data inport path and then when I am trying to serve my project I am getting this error :

> ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
>    - options has an unknown property 'data'. These properties are valid:
>      object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
>       at validate

I checked my `package.json` to just be sure that I have installed `node-sass` and `sass-loader` and I found those dependencies :

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
```

So I am a little bit confused and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I also know that I can import those `.scss` variables to every vue component in which i am going to use them but i do not like this solution.

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/style/index.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

**Directory structure**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `data` to `prependData` ...see the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

Comment: I Checked the docs but I overlooked this somehow. Thank you mate