# how to import into a component vue the global stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vue-component

I'm starting my first project in VueJS and following the documentation and tutorials I wanted to create a global stylesheet in order to use the same styles in different components. I have installed scss loader and created my stylesheet

```
$mainFont: 'PoppinsRegular, Arial';
$mainFontSemiBold: 'PoppinsSemiBold, Arial';
$mainFontItalic: 'PoppinsRegularItalic, Arial';

$primaryColor: #fff;
$secondaryColor: #dce0e6;
$tertiaryColor: #f0f4f7;
$quaternaryColor: #233240;
$quinaryColor: #0e5fa4;
$senaryColor: #14a30f;
$septenaryColor: #cd3c2d;
$octonaryColor: #6C757D;
$undenaryColor: #7e848c;
$duodenaryColor: #19b4c2;
```

I have imported this style sheet into main.js as indicated in the documentation, trying two different ways

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/scss/_variables.scss'

// this is the second way I've tested// require('./assets/scss/_variables.scss')

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

and after importing it into the main.js I have modified in my 'home' component the header of the style section and imported one of the colors declared in my style sheet

```
<style lang='scss' rel='./assets/scss/_variables'>
h3 {
  margin: 40px 0 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: $septenaryColor;
}
</style>
```

There's no doubt that I'm doing something wrong because the console throws out an error that it doesn't recognize the color reference in my styles

"Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined variable: "$septenaryColor".
on line 56 of src/components/HelloWorld.vue

> > color: $septenaryColor;

---------^"

Someone who can help me out and make me see the error of my ways.
Thank you very much in advance for your help and time

Comment: try this: [vue gloab styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59604036/how-can-i-fix-validationerror-of-sass-loader) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to modify your `vue.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `
          @import "@/style/index.scss"; // path to file with your global styles
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then all styles from this file will be accessible from every component.
More about this you can rad here: [Globally Load SASS into your Vue.js Applications](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/)